# How to add Power BI reports in Android native app

Tags: android, analytics, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am developing an Android application in which I should show Power BI reports  and tiles with drill down. I will use ADAL for login. I will use return token by ADAL to query Power BI.

I Googled but still I am not able to find a proper documentation for same.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with [What can developers do with Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-overview-of-power-bi-rest-api/). This is an introduction into Power BI development and the integration options available.

*Note: Microsoft Graph API is a separate API from Power BI REST API.*

Comment: can we add power bi on android app

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can create a web view and call the rest API from there to load mobile view. I will test this concept in a flutter app and tell you my findings.

Comment: Can you share your findings ?

Comment: wow.  this is the ultimate in pausing to build suspense!